# Should I copy an object when passing to another viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management

When i'm sending an object variable to another controller, say a Parse PFObject from an array in a menu controller to a detail view controller, should I copy that object before passing along?  Is it a weak reference if I just assign it to the object in the senders array, or does ARC make that a strong reference?

```
- (IBAction)nextScreenButtonTapped:(id)sender
{
    DestinationViewController *destinationController = [[DestinationViewController alloc] init];
    //should I copy the item before assigning?  What does ARC do here?
    destinationController.item = [self.items objectAtIndex:someIndex];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:destinationController animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: What will arc do? It will do as you instructed..! It will do what kind of property you have declared.

Comment: In this case, since your object is inside an array it will stay around as long as the array does So there is no reason to copy it.

Comment: so if the original menu controller say does a pull to refresh and refreshes a new array into its items, it would be best to make the item a copy in the destination controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the object if you don't want `destinationController` to have the original. For example, if you want to be sure that the new controller doesn't modify the original, a copy is warranted.

The reference is strong if the `item` property is declared `strong`.